# Accessing the BorderBackground of a user control in WinRT application

Tags: c#, user-controls, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a project consisting of two pages. One page is having th XAML of a User control developed by me.
The another page has the logic of cropping the image that is present in the image box on that page. I want to use my control on that page and assign the border background of the user control to the image cropped .

```
The following code is of my UserControl XAML ! The cs file for this page has no code implementation

<UserControl
    x:Class="controlMagnifier.MagnifierUsercontrol"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:controlMagnifier"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">


    <Canvas x:Name="controlCanvas" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="112,0,108,0">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform>

            </RotateTransform>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>

        <Grid Height="250" Width="176" Canvas.Left="41" Canvas.Top="40" Margin="-40,0,0,0">
            <Border x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="imgBorder" Width="150" CornerRadius="50,50,50,50" Margin="13,25,13,97">
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush  x:Name="image1"  ImageSource="/Assets/images.jpg" />
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtreading" Height="30" Width="80" Margin="0,-145,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"  FontSize="20" Text="ABC" TextAlignment="Center" />
            <!--<Image Height="120" Width="150" Margin="0,-50,0,0" Source="Assets/SmallLogo.scale-100.png" ></Image>-->
            <Path x:Name="MagnifyTip"  Data="M25.533,0C15.457,0,7.262,8.199,7.262,18.271c0,9.461,13.676,19.698,17.63,32.338    c0.085,0.273,0.34,0.459,0.626,0.457c0.287-0.004,0.538-0.192,0.619-0.467c3.836-12.951,17.666-22.856,17.667-32.33    C43.803,8.199,35.607,0,25.533,0z M25.533,32.131c-7.9,0-14.328-6.429-14.328-14.328c0-7.9,6.428-14.328,14.328-14.328    c7.898,0,14.327,6.428,14.327,14.328C39.86,25.702,33.431,32.131,25.533,32.131z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="227" Width="171" />


        </Grid>
    </Canvas>

</UserControl>
```

In the user control XAML , we can see that I have set the 
 to a static image. I want to access this user control to another page and want to assign the  element to the cropped image output on the other page. The other page MainPage.Xaml has the code for image cropping.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So the goal you want to achieve is to draw border around the image?

Comment: Actually I achieved what I had to do . I have one more issue . As u can see the xaml. The user control has a parent element as Canvas. I want to move the whole control where ever my moue moves !! any help