# Clipping Using Rectangle Geometry in WinRT application

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, rectangles, windows-rt

I was previosuly using WriteableBitmapEX library for cropping images whereever my mouse moves. It seems to be a bit slow.

I want to crop the image at any random pixels and I want to asssign that cropped region to another image control .

My problem is when I am using the clip property , I am only getting the clipped region left and the whole image is going. I want the image completely to be in the background but the cropped region should be assigned to the image control .

Here's the code .

```
 private void Image1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int CropArea = 50;
            int PointShift = CropArea / 2;
            var _rect = new RectangleGeometry();
            Point pt;
            pt = e.GetPosition(Image1);

            _rect.Rect = new Rect(pt.X - PointShift, pt.Y - PointShift, 100, 100);
            Image1.Clip = _rect;
            MagnifyTip.Image1.Source=Image1.clip; //This is what I want to do . Its not happenning. 
        }


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Image x:Name="Image1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="Image1_Tapped" >
            <Image.Source >
                <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/Jellyfish.png" />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
```

Any better solutions are welcomed becuase I have to keep on moving my finger around the image and get the updated pixel by pixel cropped image in my imagebox in my user control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note for cropping

1. Use a `RectangleGeometry` for the `Clip` property of your image (you already do that)
2. When adjusting the crop geometry - use its `Transform` property rather than creating a new geometry every time you want to recrop.
3. Updating a `WriteableBitmap` is fairly slow, so you might be able to do that once in a while - e.g. when you commit the crop rectangle, but not in real time like on each `PointerMove` event.
4. If you want real time updates you can either

   - Use another `Image` element with another `RectangleGeometry` `Clip` with a transform being a scaled version of the original transform. You could also use a copy of the original transform and scale the entire `Image` instead.
   - Use DirectX to render transformed output in a `SwapChainPanel`.
5. For the final high resolution output you can use any method since processing speed is less of a factor

   - You could use `RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync()` to render your cropped image at screen resolution. You might need to wrap the clipped image in another element like a `Grid`.
   - You can use `WriteableBitmap` to do the processing - I believe the [`WriteableBitmapEx` project](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex has methods for rotating and cropping. This is CPU based though.
   - You can use DirectX, but that could be an overkill.
   - You can use WIC with `BitmapDecoder`, though that has limited rotation capabilities: [How to resize Image in C# WinRT/winmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349611/how-to-resize-image-in-c-sharp-winrt-winmd)

Comment: I know all this theory I want something to be practical for my question . Can u help me out in my code above? I have used WriteableBitmapEx library for cropping but for larger image it sucks. can u show some demo for 4 and 5 points? I need to keep on cropping on pointermove and keep showing the updated image in the imagecontrol

Comment: I want to know about the performance ? I need great performance .it should move and clip with my finger.. no lags ! which method would be the fastest ?

Comment: Transforming clip geometry should feel fast enough, but if you want fastest - you should go the DirectX route. It's a lot of work though.

Comment: any sample for the directX clip .. I have specific question would you please be able to help me ? I need exactly like this shown in video. I am developing Windows 8.1 ap p https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ie1Z-vk4aE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: My app code is in C# , want to crop image on the bacground into my user control on mouse move . so it would be cropping for every pixel moved ! Any help ?

Comment: I found a dll for cropping that is a manged code for DirectX . SharpDX http://sharpdx.org/    . It has a cropping function. But I dont know how to use it . Would u be able to help ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that much free time. I do recommend learning sharpdx though and if you hit specific problems - you could probably get some help either here or on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that much free time.

Comment: Fine Sir .It seems to me that you are one of the best guys we have here !! Dont know who will help me If u cant ! None of my questions r being answered :(

Comment: The problem is that you would like someone to provide you a complete solution, but that is quite time consuming in the case of your problem. I have solved this problem a few times before, but this is something that takes a few hours and a lot of code. I don't have that much free time. You'd just be best off trying to solve it yourself. You might find some open source for inspiration too. Did you check the Xaml Crop Control on CodePlex?

Comment: I understand you sir ! But what If it is possible for you to share your code ! Our I would share mine where I need cropping done ! Anyways , I need complete code coz I am a Big zero in DirectX. And no tutorials too. Need to implement DirectX

Comment: I'm not a DirectX expert either - it takes a lot of time to write and modify DirectX code and I wrote most of my comments here on my phone. That said - if what you posted in the video is what you need - that is not cropping. It's a non-rectangular clipping region. You can do that in XAML fairly easily if you only need to clip an image. You would use an `Ellipse` shape and a `Fill` brush property set to an [`ImageBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagebrush.aspx) with a custom `Transform` value.

Comment: Ellipse doesnt have a Crop property in Windows 8 I think ! Anyways Thanks for your reply !

Comment: You don't want to crop the ellipse. You want an ellipse filled with an `ImageBrush` - that will give you a zoomed in circle shaped clip of your image.
Note that clipping != cropping. Clipping is typically something you do to show a UIElement clipped from its full dimensions with either rectangular or non-rectangular shape. In WinRT/XAML you only get a `Clip` property you can use with `RectangleGeometry`, but you can still fill a non-rect shape like `Ellipse` or `Path` with `ImageBrush`. Cropping is something you typically do with photos and it involves user input and yields a rectangle.

Comment: I was cropping the region and getting it circular in my user control using a border ! The performance was slow ! There is actually no zoom in the image.A high defination image looks like zoomed in. But you are telling me to Clip it ! I will try !!

Comment: Any working demo /code samples that have been implemented in WinRT?

Comment: Like I said - `Ellipse`, `Fill` = `ImageBrush`, `ImageBrush.Transform` = your transform to translate to the point being zoomed in and scaled to your zoom level. The exact calculations will depend on your image and layout.

Comment: Sure Sir , I will give it a try tomorrow and would get back to you :) Thanks for posting :)

Comment: It works well , But i need to integrate it with my user control . tried alot today but its not working ! My user control has to show the clipped region . see this please ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988606/not-getting-the-exact-cropped-region-using-writeablebitmapex-library-in-win-rt-a

Comment: The other question is about WriteableBitmapEx. I'd try to get as far as you can and then ask a specific question related to what you are trying to do.

Comment: No sir , dont get me wrong ! U saw the video which I mentioned? Right? I have to develop the same thing.Exactly same ! So I thought it was cropping , so tried WriteableBitmap but performance was slow. Then you told about Clipping and it works well. My main requirement is to attach the clipped region into the user control. That question has the link of my XAML of user control ! Thats what I want to do

Comment: umm..so I was asking you how to integrate that user control to contain that ellipse clip code ?

Comment: @Frilip Skakun - Sorry to bother you ! I am facing issues in attaching the ellipse into my user control ! Looking for answers from you !

Comment: What issues are you facing?

Comment: @Frilip Skakun - Sir , I want to attach that Ellipse to my user control. If you see the video , the clipping happens inside a user control. I have the user control as a path . The user control And the path is here  http://goo.gl/4Qbqbw . The problem is , My user control is appearing but the ellipse is moving out of the user control . I want to attach it with the user control and the user control should move according to the video

Comment: @Frilip Skakun - I tried the code u wrote and uploaded ! took the Ellipse section and wanted it to be the part of the user control. Dont have that project on this PC !If you dont get it , let me know , I would upload the project

Comment: You need to ask a separate question for each problem you want help solving. I think you are talking about another problem right now or have many separate problems that need separate questions on Stack Overflow. Bear in mind that the way Stack Overflow works is not as a free development contracting service, but a question and answer one. Your questions need to be specific and show effort from your side. Comments are not a good place to ask unrelated questions.

Comment: @Frilip Skakun - Added sir . please look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405356/clipping-using-ellipse-and-binding-it-inside-my-user-control-in-windows-rt

Comment: Were you able to look into the above posted question ?

Comment: @FilipSkakun- I have implemented the transforms in the code but I am stuck up at a place.Will u be able to spare sometime for helping me ?

Comment: We can talk about my consulting rate if you are interested. Otherwise - feel free to ask more questions on SO.

Comment: I would love to pay you but you can go ahead and see that I am a student ! I cant afford to pay a Microsoftie ... I have asked on SO but I dont think people are able to help .. Anyways Thanx :)

Comment: Can you link to a question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703191/clipping-a-low-resolution-image-using-transforms-and-assigning-it-to-my-user-con

Comment: Sir , I can assure you that when this app get launched with the latest windows version , people would love it , I hope you have seen the video..I am facing serious issues..would like to tell you that I started with cropping and tried all code you suggested in your answer, then the performance was slow ..then u suggested clipping, I went ahead with that with your guidance and back again , I need your help.Such a big community and I crave for answers !

Comment: It's not a problem of the app being great. I really don't have that much time. Gotta move the kids to the next point right now. If I find some time tonight I'll take a look. If the question is well formed - I might be able to help.

Comment: I do understand sir ! I have added the code ! you can download the app from there! Please watch the video.. I need the rotation as it is performed in the video and please take your time ! I have 2 weeks...lets both of us try

Comment: Sir , I have updated the wordings in the question's link above ! Thanks :)

Comment: I hope you will be able to look into it this weekend !

Comment: It can be both !! Anyhow this will also be released as soon as you publish windows 10 app :)

Comment: I saw the demos of the photos app at BUILD(no i wasnt there) and I was so happy that I know the person working on it ..heheheh..told my friends :) It looked awesome ! Wow !!

Comment: Really, still? And you haven't tried yourself? Can you remind me where I should go, what to look at and what to try to fix? I might have some time today.

Comment: I tried the rotation. I am not getting it ! I shared the video and asked people to help me get the same rotation in my code ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703191/clipping-a-low-resolution-image-using-transforms-and-assigning-it-to-my-user-con   this is the question where the whole code file is pasted !   The video address is http://youtu.be/0Ie1Z-vk4aE . I have updated the code https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=77EB8DD46E4379D5!93696&authkey=!AD3ll-bKr_ATrGE&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: I have fixed point 1 in the question I posted !! not getting exactly same region is point 2 but we can look at that later. The only thing that I am unable to perform is point 3 ,and the rotation as shown in the video ! not getting help !

Comment: Isn't that a maths question though? I feel like it's more of a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: not getting answers ! The rotation part ! IF you can help !! thats what all I request from you ! Someone is calling it Lerp Interpolation and all .If i put this on maths they will say this is for C# put it on StackOverflow ! If you can help ? one more request , My user control is going outside my image in both orientations , it shouldnt happen ! any fix ?

Comment: I answered that other question.

Comment: Sir , I am too much obliged ! My Windows PC crashed and HDD gone ! Please give me some time to execute it and see ! I hope you would be available for further help ! God Bless You !

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't want to clip the image you want in the background, you want two separate image controls and only clip the image you are magnifying, here is how I would do it using a Canvas and two image controls.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="canvas">
        <Image Canvas.ZIndex="0"  x:Name="Image1" ImageOpened="Image1_Opened" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="Image1_Tapped" >
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/JellyFish.png" />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
        <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" x:Name="MagnifyTip" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Image.Source >
                <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/JellyFish.png" />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Once your background image is loaded you want to set the sizes for images in the canvas.

```
    double _scaleX = 5;
    double _scaleY = 5;
    double _croppedImageWidth = 100;
    double _croppedImageHeight = 100;

    private void Image1_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Image1.MaxHeight = this.canvas.ActualHeight;
        this.Image1.MaxWidth = this.canvas.ActualWidth;
        this.MagnifyTip.MaxHeight = this.canvas.ActualHeight;
        this.MagnifyTip.MaxWidth = this.canvas.ActualWidth;
        this.MagnifyTip.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform() 
        { 
            ScaleX = _scaleX,
            ScaleY = _scaleY
        };
    }
```

Then you can set the location and scale of your magnified image in Image1_Tapped handler.

```
    private void Image1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = e.GetPosition(this.canvas);
        this.MagnifyTip.Clip = new RectangleGeometry()
        {
            Rect = new Rect()
            {
                X = pt.X, 
                Y = pt.Y, 
                Width = _croppedImageWidth / _scaleX,
                Height = _croppedImageHeight / _scaleY
            }
        };
        Canvas.SetLeft(this.MagnifyTip, -pt.X * (_scaleX - 1));
        Canvas.SetTop(this.MagnifyTip, -pt.Y * (_scaleY - 1));

        this.MagnifyTip.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

The important points are

- Use [Canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.aspx) [Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.left.aspx), [Top](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.top.aspx) and [ZIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.zindex.aspx) properties to overlay the magnified image over the background image.
- Calculate clip size and location for magnified image based off of the click point and size of your scale.
- Use [ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.scaletransform.aspx) to magnify the image.

Comment: how would it work with my usercontrol as there is an image box inside the control . I want to tap my finger on the parent image, my user control appears with the cropped area around my finger , now I keep on moving my finger around the image and whereever my finger is , my user control is getting updated with the new cropped image ! Currently I would like to drop the idea of magnification.

Comment: the movement of the user control is very necessary. he user control can move top , bottom , right , left and that with the finger.so sometime my finger would be on the user control to move it up . check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740086/zoom-cropped-pixels-in-a-user-control/28900396?noredirect=1#comment46134330_28900396

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put your usercontrol in the canvas as well?

Comment: no specific reason ! but do u really think It would work as efficient as I want  it to be? My WriteableBitmap sucks . and how to dynamically assign my user control's imagebox to the image?  check my user control XAML .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988606/not-getting-the-exact-cropped-region-using-writeablebitmapex-library-in-win-rt-a

Comment: Esentially instead of updating the image itself in the InkCanvas_PointerMoved you would just want to set the transform property ex.  MagnifyTip.image1.Transform = new ScaleTransform() { CenterX = xValue1/4, CenterY = yValue1/4, ScaleX = 2, ScaleY = 2 };

Comment: And this would give me the cropped Image everytime on my pointer moved. But what If I dont want to scale the image. Just show the cropped region ?

Comment: I tried doin that. Don't know whats not working for me. Please look into the project. I have added my user control too. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=70BF0E66B131F8C7!23751&authkey=!ABoARj6lZOGy0Os&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: The image shouldn't be an imagebrush, too many canvases, here take a look at this it isn't perfect but should be enough to get you started, only part seems to be rounding the corners https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C24515A7B235C447%21734

Comment: Did u modify my code? I am on a mac system. See , I need that user control to show the cropped image and I want the cropping to be awesome! The user control should move with my finger and rotate as per requirenment !

Comment: rounding at the corners has to be done with border only ! Anyhow , I see that you have put on a <Image> tag that seems to be commented ! Will check this solution on tuesday and will get back to u !

Comment: why cant I put that image control directly inside the user control rather than putting it on MainPage.XAML ?

Comment: Actually its good ! but its not helpig me. I need it to be prefect and I am trying so many things. The image would be dynamic and the user control has to clip ..check the solution I uploaded !

Comment: That happens because I didn't hide the image at the start, I updated it.

Comment: try to put the image inside the user control . I am having issues with it..the image control is getting bigger and not looking good inside the user control I made

Comment: Bro, I am working on a very big project and this cropping should happen exactly the way it happens in the video. The user loads the image dynamically using file picker and that user control should crop the image . The user control should come just above where I tap and hold for a while and moves with my finger . Same thing i have to develop. No deviations

Comment: I hear you but I have a day job. What you could try to do is make three image controls that fit under the border of your custom control and it will basically do what you want. Basically replicate the same behavior for all the image controls just offset in height or width which ever fits better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro ! I understand it !but i have been trying so many solutions and nothing seems to work for me ! If possible please take this weekend and frame the solution you want me to use ! I will be very thankful to you

Comment: @Slowbrochaocho - Link sir ?

Comment: Sir , Thanks! I would see this one !! I am also not on a Windows PC now !! I will give you bounty coz you have been trying so hard ! Can we talk on chat?

Comment: would you be able to initiate the chat in stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73506/discussion-between-slowbrochacho-and-apoorv).