# Clipping Using Ellipse and binding it inside my user control in Windows RT

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, clipping

I have an image and I am clipping the mouse area using an Ellipse in which I am quite successful.

But I want that ellipse to be a part of my user control and the user control should move along with my finger and the clipping Ellipse should be inside the user control .
The complete project can be downloaded from [here](http://1drv.ms/1Fvqm0O)

My **UserControl'sXAML** is

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App78.Magnifier"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App78"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="230"
    Width="170">


    <Grid Height="230" Width="170">
        <Path Data="M25.533,0C15.457,0,7.262,8.199,7.262,18.271c0,9.461,13.676,19.698,17.63,32.338 c0.085,0.273,0.34,0.459,0.626,0.457c0.287-0.004,0.538-0.192,0.619-0.467c3.836-12.951,17.666-22.856,17.667-32.33 C43.803,8.199,35.607,0,25.533,0z M25.533,32.131c-7.9,0-14.328-6.429-14.328-14.328c0-7.9,6.428-14.328,14.328-14.328 c7.898,0,14.327,6.428,14.327,14.328C39.86,25.702,33.431,32.131,25.533,32.131z"
              Fill="#FFF4F4F5"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="Black"
              UseLayoutRounding="False"
              Height="227"
              Width="171" ></Path>
            <Ellipse x:Name="MagnifierEllipse" x:FieldModifier="public"  Opacity="1" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="150" Height="150" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="11,8,0,0" >
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="MagnifierTransform" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush
                    ImageSource="http://blog.al.com/space-news/2009/04/iss015e22574.jpg"
                    Stretch="None"
                    AlignmentX="Left"
                    AlignmentY="Top">
                        <ImageBrush.Transform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform x:FieldModifier="public"
                                x:Name="PositionTransform"/>
                                <ScaleTransform x:FieldModifier="public"
                                x:Name="ZoomTransform"/>
                                <TranslateTransform x:FieldModifier="public"
                                x:Name="CenterTransform" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </ImageBrush.Transform>
                    </ImageBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My **MainPage.XAML** is

```
<Page
    x:Class="App78.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App78"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid
        x:Name="LayoutGrid"
        Margin="0,0"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        Holding="LayoutGrid_Holding"
        PointerMoved="LayoutGrid_OnPointerMoved"
        PointerWheelChanged="LayoutGrid_OnPointerWheelChanged">
        <Image
            x:Name="BigImage"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            Source="http://blog.al.com/space-news/2009/04/iss015e22574.jpg" />


                <!--<Ellipse 
            x:Name="MagnifierEllipse"
            Opacity="1"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            IsHitTestVisible="False"
            Width="150"
            Height="150"
            Stroke="White"
            StrokeThickness="3"
            Margin="-100">
                    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform
                    x:Name="MagnifierTransform"/>
                    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush
                    ImageSource="http://blog.al.com/space-news/2009/04/iss015e22574.jpg"
                    Stretch="None"
                    AlignmentX="Left"
                    AlignmentY="Top">
                            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TranslateTransform
                                x:Name="PositionTransform"/>
                                    <ScaleTransform
                                x:Name="ZoomTransform"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform
                                x:Name="CenterTransform" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </ImageBrush.Transform>
                        </ImageBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>-->
        <local:Magnifier x:Name="MagnifierTip" Visibility="Visible" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Please see the **commented section** of **Ellipse** , If I uncomment  , I clearly get a Ellipse that is doing the clip.

My main requirenment is to get the Ellipse inside the user control , please refer the [video](http://youtu.be/0Ie1Z-vk4aE) for more clarification

My **MainPage.XAML.CS** has the following code

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace App78
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private double zoomScale = 2;
        private double pointerX = 0;
        private double pointerY = 0;
        private const double MinZoomScale = .25;
        private const double MaxZoomScale = 32;


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            var bi = (BitmapImage)BigImage.Source;
            bi.ImageOpened += bi_ImageOpened;
            this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;
        }

        void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateImageLayout();
        }

        void bi_ImageOpened(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateImageLayout();
        }

        private void UpdateImageLayout()
        {
            var bi = (BitmapImage)BigImage.Source;
            if (bi.PixelWidth < this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth &&
                bi.PixelHeight < this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight)
            {
                this.BigImage.Stretch = Stretch.None;
            }
            else
            {
                this.BigImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            }

            this.UpdateMagnifier();
        }

        private void LayoutGrid_OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           // MagnifierTip.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.LayoutGrid);
            this.pointerX = point.Position.X;
            this.pointerY = point.Position.Y;
            this.UpdateMagnifier();
        }

        private void UpdateMagnifier()
        {
            var bi = (BitmapImage)BigImage.Source;

            double offsetX = 0;
            double offsetY = 0;
            double imageScale = 1;

            var imageRatio = (double)bi.PixelWidth / bi.PixelHeight;
            var gridRatio = this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth / this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight;

            if (bi.PixelWidth < this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth &&
                bi.PixelHeight < this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight)
            {
                offsetX = 0.5 * (this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth - bi.PixelWidth);
                offsetY = 0.5 * (this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight - bi.PixelHeight);
                //imageScale = 1; - remains
            }
            else if (imageRatio < gridRatio)
            {
                offsetX = 0.5 * (this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth - imageRatio * this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight);
                offsetY = 0;
                imageScale = BigImage.ActualHeight / bi.PixelHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                offsetX = 0;
                offsetY = 0.5 * (this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight - this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth / imageRatio);
                imageScale = BigImage.ActualWidth / bi.PixelWidth;
            }

            MagnifierTip.MagnifierTransform.X = this.pointerX;
           MagnifierTip.MagnifierTransform.Y = this.pointerY;
           MagnifierTip.PositionTransform.X = (-this.pointerX + offsetX) / imageScale;
           MagnifierTip.PositionTransform.Y = (-this.pointerY + offsetY) / imageScale;
           MagnifierTip. ZoomTransform.ScaleX = imageScale * zoomScale;
           MagnifierTip.ZoomTransform.ScaleY = imageScale * zoomScale;
           MagnifierTip.CenterTransform.X = MagnifierTip.MagnifierEllipse.ActualWidth / 2 - MagnifierTip.MagnifierEllipse.StrokeThickness / 2;
           MagnifierTip.CenterTransform.Y = MagnifierTip.MagnifierEllipse.ActualHeight / 2 - MagnifierTip.MagnifierEllipse.StrokeThickness / 2;
        }

        private void LayoutGrid_OnPointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.GetCurrentPoint(this.LayoutGrid).Properties.MouseWheelDelta > 0)
            {
                zoomScale = Math.Max(MinZoomScale, Math.Min(MaxZoomScale, zoomScale * 1.2));
            }
            else
            {
                zoomScale = Math.Max(MinZoomScale, Math.Min(MaxZoomScale, zoomScale / 1.2));
            }

            this.UpdateMagnifier();
        }

        private void LayoutGrid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          //  MagnifierTip.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Magnifier only supposed to be visible when you are touching the screen? (or holding the mouse)...
If yes, Manipulations are the solution probably.
Anyway I will take a look at your code, but it would help if you could answer this.

Comment: I tap and hold on the image then the magnifier appears. So I add and use "Holding" event in my image or canvas .

Comment: So it works like this , when i tap and hold , lets say for 1 second, the user control appears just above the point of touch, i can move up down right left or anywhere on the screen , the user control should move with my finger as fast as my finger moves , and clip the area around the pixels around my finger. when i release my finger , the user control hides. I dont think ManipulationDelta is required , though it would work but only when the finger is on the user control (move it up) , rest of the times , finger is just below the user control

Comment: You are right (ManipulationDelta is not need), that's why I needed some clarification on that.
I did something similar both ways (both with and without Manipulation Delta), let me just take a loot at your project. Maybe I can figure out what needs to be changed.

Comment: I hope you are having clarification of what I am trying to implement ! look at the video in the question

Comment: I saw it. I think I got it working (the basic stuff obviously, I still left a lot of things for you to do, don't worry :)
Let me just answer...

Comment: @DinisVieira need your help again ! the previous code has some issues ! Loading small images, I am not getting the correct region in the center of the control !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to get your MagnifierTransform to the "root" Grid of your Magnifier UserControl.
Also the CenterTransform doesn't seem to be needed in my opinion.
The other last change is in the MainPage, making the User Control aligned to Top/Left so that the TranslateTransforms make sense.

Just as a bonus, I got the updated project [here](http://1drv.ms/19Z3SKc) , also with pointer pressed/released events to show/hide the magnifier. Be warned that "Holding" doesn't work with most mouse devices. Source: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
I also added comments on my changes (comments start with DV:).
It's not perfect and there's obviously still a lot for you to implement but hopefully this is what you needed.

For whoever doesn't want to download the project I'll leave the updated code here:
**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App78.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App78"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid
        x:Name="LayoutGrid"
        Margin="0,0"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        Holding="LayoutGrid_Holding"
        PointerMoved="LayoutGrid_OnPointerMoved"
        PointerWheelChanged="LayoutGrid_OnPointerWheelChanged"
        PointerPressed="LayoutGrid_OnPointerPressed"
        PointerReleased="LayoutGrid_OnPointerReleased">
        <Image
            x:Name="BigImage"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            Source="http://blog.al.com/space-news/2009/04/iss015e22574.jpg" />

        <local:Magnifier VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="MagnifierTip" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace App78
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private double zoomScale = 2;
        private double pointerX = 0;
        private double pointerY = 0;
        private const double MinZoomScale = .25;
        private const double MaxZoomScale = 32;


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            var bi = (BitmapImage)BigImage.Source;
            bi.ImageOpened += bi_ImageOpened;
            this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;
        }

        void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateImageLayout();
        }

        void bi_ImageOpened(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateImageLayout();
        }

        private void UpdateImageLayout()
        {
            var bi = (BitmapImage)BigImage.Source;
            if (bi.PixelWidth < this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth &&
                bi.PixelHeight < this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight)
            {
                this.BigImage.Stretch = Stretch.None;
            }
            else
            {
                this.BigImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            }

            this.UpdateMagnifier();
        }

        private void LayoutGrid_OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //DV: If pointer is not in contact we can ignore it
            if (!e.Pointer.IsInContact) { return; }

            var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.LayoutGrid);
            this.pointerX = point.Position.X;
            this.pointerY = point.Position.Y;
            this.UpdateMagnifier();
        }

        private void UpdateMagnifier()
        {
            var bi = (BitmapImage)BigImage.Source;

            double offsetX = 0;
            double offsetY = 0;
            double imageScale = 1;

            var imageRatio = (double)bi.PixelWidth / bi.PixelHeight;
            var gridRatio = this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth / this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight;

            if (bi.PixelWidth < this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth &&
                bi.PixelHeight < this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight)
            {
                offsetX = 0.5 * (this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth - bi.PixelWidth);
                offsetY = 0.5 * (this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight - bi.PixelHeight);
                //imageScale = 1; - remains
            }
            else if (imageRatio < gridRatio)
            {
                offsetX = 0.5 * (this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth - imageRatio * this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight);
                offsetY = 0;
                imageScale = BigImage.ActualHeight / bi.PixelHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                offsetX = 0;
                offsetY = 0.5 * (this.LayoutGrid.ActualHeight - this.LayoutGrid.ActualWidth / imageRatio);
                imageScale = BigImage.ActualWidth / bi.PixelWidth;
            }

            //DV: This is probably not need anymore
           //MagnifierTip.MagnifierTransform.X = this.pointerX;
           //MagnifierTip.MagnifierTransform.Y = this.pointerY;
            MagnifierTip.PositionTransform.X = (-this.pointerX + offsetX) / imageScale;
            MagnifierTip.PositionTransform.Y = (-this.pointerY + offsetY) / imageScale;

            //DV: I haven't tested the Scaling/Zoom
            MagnifierTip.ZoomTransform.ScaleX = imageScale * zoomScale;
            MagnifierTip.ZoomTransform.ScaleY = imageScale * zoomScale;

            MagnifierTip.CenterTransform.X = MagnifierTip.MagnifierEllipse.ActualWidth / 2 - MagnifierTip.MagnifierEllipse.StrokeThickness / 2;
            MagnifierTip.CenterTransform.Y = MagnifierTip.MagnifierEllipse.ActualHeight / 2 - MagnifierTip.MagnifierEllipse.StrokeThickness / 2;

            //DV: I added a GlobalGrid Transform which translates every children
            MagnifierTip.MagnifierTransformGrid.X = this.pointerX - (MagnifierTip.ActualWidth / 2);
            MagnifierTip.MagnifierTransformGrid.Y = this.pointerY - (MagnifierTip.ActualHeight); ;

        }

        private void LayoutGrid_OnPointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.GetCurrentPoint(this.LayoutGrid).Properties.MouseWheelDelta > 0)
            {
                zoomScale = Math.Max(MinZoomScale, Math.Min(MaxZoomScale, zoomScale * 1.2));
            }
            else
            {
                zoomScale = Math.Max(MinZoomScale, Math.Min(MaxZoomScale, zoomScale / 1.2));
            }

            this.UpdateMagnifier();
        }


        //DV: Holding usually only works with touch https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
        private void LayoutGrid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }

        //DV: pointer pressed supports both mouse and touch but fires immeadiatley. You'll have to figure out a delay strategy or using holding for touch and right click for mouse
        private void LayoutGrid_OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MagnifierTip.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        }

        //DV: pointer released supports both mouse and touch.
        private void LayoutGrid_OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MagnifierTip.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

**Magnifier.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App78.Magnifier"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App78"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="230"
    Width="170">


    <Grid Height="230" Width="170">

        <!-- DV: This is the global transform I added -->
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="MagnifierTransformGrid" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse Opacity="1" Visibility="Visible" Fill="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="135" Height="128"  StrokeThickness="3" Margin="0,17,0,0" />
        <Ellipse x:Name="MagnifierEllipse" x:FieldModifier="public" Opacity="1" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="150" Height="150" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="11,8,0,0" >
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush
                    ImageSource="http://blog.al.com/space-news/2009/04/iss015e22574.jpg"
                    Stretch="None"
                    AlignmentX="Left"
                    AlignmentY="Top">
                    <ImageBrush.Transform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform x:FieldModifier="public"
                                x:Name="CenterTransform"/>
                            <TranslateTransform x:FieldModifier="public"
                                x:Name="PositionTransform"/>
                            <ScaleTransform x:FieldModifier="public"
                                x:Name="ZoomTransform"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </ImageBrush.Transform>
                </ImageBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <Path Data="M25.533,0C15.457,0,7.262,8.199,7.262,18.271c0,9.461,13.676,19.698,17.63,32.338 c0.085,0.273,0.34,0.459,0.626,0.457c0.287-0.004,0.538-0.192,0.619-0.467c3.836-12.951,17.666-22.856,17.667-32.33 C43.803,8.199,35.607,0,25.533,0z M25.533,32.131c-7.9,0-14.328-6.429-14.328-14.328c0-7.9,6.428-14.328,14.328-14.328 c7.898,0,14.327,6.428,14.327,14.328C39.86,25.702,33.431,32.131,25.533,32.131z"
              Fill="#FFF4F4F5"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="Black"
              UseLayoutRounding="False"
              Height="227"
              Width="171" ></Path>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Umm , I just have to use touch events only ! So holding will help! there is no way in which mouse is involved ! only touch inputs in the App ! I am yet to run the code ! will update you in a while ! thanks for your input

Comment: Checked it , found some issues like , the place where my finger is , should be shown at the center when the clipping is done.when u move the mouse to the edges of the screen , there is some problem too, I think centertransform does the centering of the area. can u look into it ?

Comment: You are right, centertransform is indeed needed and solves the "centering".
The edges thing is easy, just need another ellipse behind the "clipping one" with the same background that the app has. (this might need to be different in complex apps)
I will update the project/answer to reflect this.

Comment: Already updated both the code in the answer and the project (in the answer).
Should be closer to what you wanted now. :)

Comment: I  will again have a look ! do really think that the way it is being shown in the video , we will be able to achieve? there is a point coming inside the ellipse that shows the line connectivity . Secondly the way it rotates it seems to be super complex to me :(

Comment: My last solution which was just with a single ellipse was able to show the edges very well ! ummm....download the project from here and see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1192076/MagnifierApp.zip

Comment: I checked it, it has exactly the same problem. It also needs the fake background ellipse there :)

Comment: To get what you have in the video will definitely need some more work.
I would start by having a CenterTransform and a RotateTransform on the MagnifierGrid (not the ellipse).
Getting the right formula for that centering/rotation when it reaches the edges will require some work though.
But it's the way to do it on my opinion.

Comment: but you know , the rotation is super complex , see it , it rotates very slowly and it works very intelligently . possibly for you to try the way it goes ? can i have your email id ?

Comment: The project I shared with u seems to be optimal. Like when it is coming to the edges , half is being shown as an image part and other half as the background grid , why do we need a fake ellipse . see the video again. We need the same solution friend

Comment: Take a closer look... [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29dwsgx&s=8) :) .... 
I though you had the code for the Android version. Without that it will be more complex for sure, but it's in the lines of what I told you, basically manipulation rotation/center/translation of the MainGrid when it's in the Edges.
Unfortunately I don't have the time to do a deep dive into what the specific formula will be, I'm in the middle of a bunch of problems myself :)
Can only wish you good luck.
And of course if you find any specific problem just ask a question.

Comment: Thanks Bro. I dont have the code , If I would have had , I would have copied the formula :P

Comment: as the original position of the control is set to top and left, tapping anywhere on the screen shows it first at the top position ! when removing the horizontal and vertical alignment , its not coming at the clicked pixel ..

Comment: Bro, I was testing the app, loaded a very small image , I am not getting the exact mouse location in the user control..can u recheck ? we need to get the pixelpoint in the center of the user control